# How do you select multiple columns from multiple tables along with total cost?

Tags: database, oracle, select

I have four tables, but for this I only need three tables, and I want to display the customerid, orderid, productid, quantity and the total cost which isn't in any table but need to calculate? so far  I have managed to get it to display total cost for one order with the order id, but I want it to display all the columns mentioned above

**Order**:

```
order_id(primary key)
customer_id( foreign key)
```

**orderline**:

```
orderid(fk) + productid(fk) (pk)
quantity
```

**product**:

```
productid(pk)
price
```

What I have done is

```
select orderid, sum(rowcost) as totalcost
  from (select o.quantity, o.productid, o.orderid, os.customerid, p.price, 
              (o.quantity * p.price) as rowcost
         from orderline o 
              inner join order os 
                      on o.orderid = os.orderid 
              inner join product p 
                      on p.productid = o.productid 
         where productid = 123) 
 group by orderid;
```

Now I want it to display all the orderids along with the productid, customerid, totalcost, orderid and quantity. The list should follow customerid order.

How would I do this?

when I add more variables in the select, it gives me errors. I have tried many ways, none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you want something like this:

```
select o.quantity, o.productid, o.orderid, os.customerid, p.price, 
       (o.quantity * p.price) as rowcost,
       sum(o.quantity * p.price) over (partition by os.customerid) as totalcost
  from orderline o 
       inner join order os 
               on o.orderid = os.orderid 
       inner join product p 
               on p.productid = o.productid 
 where p.productid = 123
```

or this, to keep the sum correct if you wanted to filter afterwards on a product

```
select *
  from (select o.quantity, o.productid, o.orderid, os.customerid, p.price, 
               (o.quantity * p.price) as rowcost,
               sum(o.quantity * p.price) over (partition by os.customerid) as totalcost
          from orderline o 
               inner join order os 
                       on o.orderid = os.orderid 
               inner join product p 
                       on p.productid = o.productid)
 where productid = 123--or just remove this where clause
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3103d/1

Comment: yeah But I have tried that it din't work, also I want it to display the total of all the productsids not just one.

Comment: @user2216093 can you define "didnt work". your original SQL had the `where productid = 123` so i kept that..you can remove it if you wanted all productid's. it may be helpful if you mean that it's not giving the required output, to add sample data for each table and the required output you want.

Comment: It doesn't work as in it gave an error, I performed that query before posting and it didn't work

Comment: @user2216093 was it complaining about ambigious column? ive added `p.` to productid (your original query must have had the same problem). also see fiddle example.

Comment: Yeah It gave that error.But p. worked with the query I have mentioned in my question, and that query works but i want it display all teh other columns along with the total.

Comment: @user2216093 that is what my query is doing..all columns are displayed. check the fiddle too for an example.

Comment: Yeah but the query is displaying an error which doesn't make sense to me as the query makes sense and should work

Comment: This query don't work either. I am using * as I have got other attributes that I have not mentioned here. But could it be anything to do with the group by functtion and nvl?

Comment: @user2216093 my examples are on oracle but if you're using `*` be careful, as you have to say `select o.*, sum(o.quantity * p.price) over (partition by os.customerid) as totalcost` and NOT `select *, sum(o.quantity * p.price) over (partition by os.customerid) as totalcost` as when you have `*` without a qualifier, no other column can be selected. eg http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3103d/5 in the 2nd example. note that if you have duplicate col names then you'll get errors (you have to explicitly name them to avoid confusion)

Comment: Okay that's fine, but how would I get this to work now? I have tried all teh ways they don't work. even on fiddle it says the way I tried before